How to set default background color for table, then apply custom background color based on cell value?
I want to set the background color of the whole table, then change the background color to red if the cell in the "DATA_PASS" column is false.
The following is my code by I can't seem to get the applymap to work.
import pandas as pd

# Define the data
data = {
    'Column1': [10, 20, 30],
    'Column2': [40, 50, 60],
    'DATA_PASS': [True, False, True]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to highlight the cell in red if DATA_PASS is False
def highlight_data_pass(val):
    return 'background-color: red' if val == False else ''

# Apply the styles and properties
styler = df.style \
    .applymap(highlight_data_pass, subset=['DATA_PASS']) \
    .set_table_styles([
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': [
            ('background-color', '#606060'), 
            ('color', 'white'), 
            ('width', '100px'), 
            ('height', '30px')
        ]},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': [
            ('background-color', '#A9A9A9'), 
            ('color', 'black'), 
            ('width', '250px'), 
            ('height', '30px')
        ]}
    ]) \
    .set_properties(**{
        'border': '1px solid black'
    })

# Display the styled DataFrame
styler

The red cell is visible if I do the following but I lose the colors of other cells that I want.
styler = df.style.applymap(highlight_data_pass, subset=['DATA_PASS'])

Reversing the order also did not work, the cell did not turn red.
styler = df.style.set_table_styles([
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': [
            ('background-color', '#606060'), 
            ('color', 'white'), 
            ('width', '100px'), 
            ('height', '30px')
        ]},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': [
            ('background-color', '#A9A9A9'), 
            ('color', 'black'), 
            ('width', '250px'), 
            ('height', '30px')
        ]}
    ]) \
    .set_properties(**{
        'border': '1px solid black'
    }) \
    .applymap(highlight_data_pass, subset=['DATA_PASS']) \


Yeah, the the set_table_styles is overriding the cell properties styling.  You might have to style the cells without using the set_table_styles method.

For the td selector...

You can try something like this:
import pandas as pd

# Define the data
data = {
    "Column1": [10, 20, 30],
    "Column2": [40, 50, 60],
    "DATA_PASS": [True, False, True],
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def highlight_data_pass(val):
    return (
        "background-color: red"
        if not val
        else "background-color: #A9A9A9"
    )


# Apply the styles and properties
styler = (
    df.style.set_table_styles(
        [
            {
                "selector": "th",
                "props": [
                    ("background-color", "#606060"),
                    ("color", "white"),
                    ("width", "100px"),
                    ("height", "30px"),
                ],
            },
                    {'selector': 'td', 'props': [
#                         ('background-color', '#A9A9A9'),
                        ('color', 'black'),
                        ('width', '250px'),
                        ('height', '30px')
                    ]}
        ]
    )
    .set_properties(**{"border": "1px solid black"})
    .map(highlight_data_pass)
)


# Display the styled DataFrame
styler

Output:

Note: In newer version of pandas applymap is deprecated use map.  And, took out the subset and apply highligth_data_pass to entire dataframe styler.
